# Creating a Grid in QGIS of with 1meter intervals

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I need to create a grid over my QGIS shapefile, with 1m intervals.
I know the procedure of creating the grid; view -> decorations -> grid

My question is, what is the x and y intervals that I need to provide in order to get a grid with 1 meter intervals, when I am creating a line grid?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Do you want to show a grid on your map layout (for printing) or actually create a new grid geometry (shapefile) to save with your data?

Comment: Hello! creating a shapefile would be the ideal. is it possible to create such a grid as a shapefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the toolbox and search for the `creategrid` tool.

Set the grid-type you want and an extent (you can either draw a box on the map or select an existing layer).

Horizontal and vertical distance is 1 (obviously, since you want to create a 1x1 m grid) and don't forget to set the grid CRS to something based on `m` which fits your project area, most likely a UTM-strip.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It worked. For anybody who's got the same problem, I used the EPSG: 32644 - WGS 84/UTM zone 44 N Coordinate Reference System to use meters scale.

Comment: Yeah, but keep in mind that [Zone 44N](http://epsg.io/32644) is only suited for the area "between 78°E and 84°E, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. China. India. Kazakhstan. Kyrgyzstan. Nepal. Russian Federation. Sri Lanka."